# Understand List in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I trying to understand how list works. 
I have a table name ABC. I use this method to add all the data into list.

```
List<ABC> abc = getABC("123");
for(ABC a: abc)
{ 
    System.out.println(p.getValue());
}
```

**Code**

```
@Override
    public List<ABC> getABC(String id) {
         StringBuilder bf = new StringBuilder();
         bf.append("SELECT a from ABC a ");
         bf.append("WHERE a.id = :id ");
         return em.createQuery(bf.toString())
                 .setParameter("id", id)
                 .getResultList();            
    }
```

But if I want to write like this, what does this mean and what is the logic I can write ?

```
ABC abc = getABC(id);
```

**Code**

```
public ABC getABC(String id )
{
    // how to write this logic ?
}
```

The first one, it consider  as list, how about the second ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query SQL framework surely also supports a method that returns a single result:

```
 public ABC getABC(String id) {
     StringBuilder bf = new StringBuilder();
     bf.append("SELECT a from ABC a ");
     bf.append("WHERE a.id = :id ");
     return (ABC) em.createQuery(bf.toString())
             .setParameter("id", id)
             .getSingleResult();            
}
```

Comment: I get error in `getSingleResult();` .Object cannot be converted to ABC

Comment: @JohnJoe don't forget to cast to `(ABC)`.

Answer (score 1):

`List<ABC> abc` is declaring `abc` as List of objects of class ABC. A List holds a collection of obects.

`ABC abc` is declaring `abc` as a single object of class ABC.

Comment: I get error in `getSingleResult();` .Object cannot be converted to ABC

Answer (score 1):

> But if I want to write like this, what does this mean

That means you are not returning `List<ABC>` instead you are returning an instance of `ABC` class.

> and what is the logic I can write ?

Declare a member variable in your ABC class and use setter/getter.

```
class ABC
{
private List<ABC> abc;
// initialize the list in constructor
//use getter and setter

}
```

Then, you could create an instance of ABC and use setter method to set value inside `getABC` method.

Obviously, you could also make use of solution, which @Thomas posted.

Comment: I get error in `getSingleResult();` .Object cannot be converted to ABC

Comment: @JohnJoe you need to cast to ABC. Also, do not mix the solution provided by Thomas and mine. Both are different approach and outcome is different

Answer (score 1):

Use getSingleResult that will return only the id that matches

```
@Override
    public ABC getABC(String id) {
         StringBuilder bf = new StringBuilder();
         bf.append("SELECT a from ABC a");
         bf.append("WHERE a.id = :id ");
         return (ABC) em.createQuery(bf.toString())
                 .setParameter("id", id)
                 .getSingleResult();            
    }
```

Comment: I get error in `getSingleResult();` .Object cannot be converted to ABC